# update div after jeditable submit in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jeditable, in-place-editor

i want to submit the text from jeditable, store it in the database and then i don´t want to render the updated text back to jeditable field, i want to update the whole div in which the jeditable field (and maybee other text fields) is.

f.e.

i change the username via jeditable inplace editor, then i store the changes in the db and now i want to update the complete div which contains the username (in place editor) and also other divs, cause after the username changes, the email changes, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the callback function to make a second AJAX call to get the new data.

```
  $('.editable').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', { 
     type     : 'textarea',
     submit   : 'OK',
     callback : function(value, settings) {
        $("AREATOBEUPDATED").load("URL THAT RETURNS FULL CONTENT OF AREA");
      }
  });
```